# How to find the length of each element of a multidimensional array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

Suppose we have a `n-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}` in Julia, listed below:

1) Element 1: `1-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  .  141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]`

2) Element 2: `2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10  .  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
 [51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60  .  141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150]`

and so on.

Actually, each element represents the connected components of several undirected graphs. Is there a command or a simple way to obtain the length of each deepest array (the number of connected components)? That is:

1) `150`

2) `50 and 100`

and so on.

Thank you!!

Comment: I think I found the answer, so I can share it with everyone! But other suggestions are welcome obviously! So, imagine the `n-element Array{Array{Array{Int64,1},1},1}` is stored in the object `A`. We can do `length.(A[k])` for the k-th element. And then, with the `map` command we can obtain all the lengths.

Comment: I would simply redesign the program and not use `Array{Array{Array...}`. There are other types in the JuliaArrays organization for this, which are more efficient.

Comment: Ah nice!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

```
a = [[rand(3), rand(4)], [rand(5)]]
```

the version you already commented would be

```
julia> map(x -> length.(x), a)
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [3, 4]
 [5]
```

Alternatively, the following in my opinion would be more readable:

```
julia> [[length(x) for x in y] for y in a]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [3, 4]
 [5]
```

But @juliohm is right, there might be better data structures than deeply nested arrays.  Maybe have a look at `LightGraphs.jl`, if you're dealing with graph problems.

Comment: Yes thanks! It is precisely from `LightGraphs.jl` i obtained this structure, after applying the command `connected_components` to a list of graphs.